# IIS Rewrite with and/or without trailing slash

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm having trouble with my redirectmap, and I wonder what the best approach would be.

So far, I have a rewritemap with:

```
<add key="/old-folder/old-pagename" value="/new-folder/new-pagename" />
<add key="/old-pagename" value="/new-pagename" />
```

And in my web.config, I have this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps.config"></rewriteMaps>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*[^/])" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{Redirects:{PATH_INFO}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The problem is that, looking at Google Search Console, both `https://example.com/old-pagename` and `https://example.com/old-pagename/` (with trailing slash) are found.

The only solution I have now, is to double my `rewritemaps.config` and make sure every rewrite is included with and withoud a trailing slash.

Surely, there has to be a nicer way without doubling the redirectlist? Can't I just ignore the trailing slash via the match rule?

What is best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following rule in web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="Redirects">
            <add key="old-folder/old-pagename" value="/new-folder/new-pagename"/>
            <add key="old-pagename" value="/new-pagename"/>
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect rule1 for Redirects">
            <match url="^(.+?)/?$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{Redirects:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This rule works for me, hope it will help you too. If still not working, please let me know and I will help you further.